# I am getting error on line 109 , "ORA-06533: Subscript beyond count"

Tags: sql, plsql

I am getting error on line 109 , "ORA-06533: Subscript beyond count". This only occurs when if number of records for a particular employee is more then 70.

Error report:

```
ORA-06533: Subscript beyond count
ORA-06512: at line 109
06533. 00000 -  "Subscript beyond count"
*Cause:    An in-limit subscript was greater than the count of a varray
           or too large for a nested table.


  declare

      type v_dt is varray(30000) of date;
          v_visit v_dt := v_dt();

      i number :=0;
      j number :=0;
      v_max_prod number :=0;
      v_max_visit number :=0;
      v_create_sql varchar2(4000 char) :='';
      v_insert_sql varchar2(4000 char) :='';
      v_insert_sql_val varchar2(4000 char) :='';
      v_create_col_head varchar2(4000 char) :='';
      v_insert_col_head varchar2(4000 char) :='';
      v_tbl_ext  number;
      cursor al is select distinct team_name,employee_name from TMP_BMS_RPT_3 where  employee_name in ('JAY DESAI')  order by employee_name;
--(Here i am taking an example of employee whose having more then 200 records in TMP_BMS_RPT_3 table and i am getting this error. )    

    begin

      select max(total_call) into v_max_visit from TMP_BMS_RPT_3 ;
      select count(1) into v_tbl_ext from tab where lower(tname) like 'tmp_bms_monthly_report';



      if v_tbl_ext >= 1 then
        execute immediate 'drop table tmp_BMS_monthly_report';
        execute immediate 'drop table tmp_BMS_monthly_rpt_heading';
      end if;
      v_create_sql := 'create table tmp_BMS_monthly_report (
                           team_name varchar2(100),
                             CCA_USER_ID varchar2(100),
                           EMPLOYEE_NAME  varchar2(100),
                           FLM  varchar2(100),
                           ad_Sales varchar2(100),
                           Client_Customer_id varchar2(100),
                           customer_name varchar2(100),
                           specialty varchar2(100),
                           brand varchar2(100),
                           class varchar2(100),
                           Planned_calls Number,
                           total_call number,
                           Last_visit DATE';



      v_create_col_head := 'create table tmp_BMS_monthly_rpt_heading (
                           team_name varchar2(100),
                           CCA_USER_ID varchar2(100),
                           EMPLOYEE_NAME  varchar2(100),
                           FLM  varchar2(100),
                           ad_Sales varchar2(100),
                           Client_Customer_id varchar2(100),
                           customer_name varchar2(100),
                           specialty varchar2(100),
                           brand varchar2(100),
                           class varchar2(100),
                           Planned_calls varchar2(100),
                           total_call varchar2(100),
                           Last_visit varchar2(100)';

       for i in 1..v_max_visit loop
          v_create_sql := v_create_sql || ',Visit_' ||i ||'     date';
          v_create_col_head := v_create_col_head || ',Visit_' ||i ||'       varchar2(50)';
      end loop i;
      v_create_sql := v_create_sql ||')';
      v_create_col_head := v_create_col_head ||')';
      execute immediate v_create_sql;
      execute immediate v_create_col_head;

      v_insert_col_head := 'insert into tmp_BMS_monthly_rpt_heading values (''Team_name'',''CCA_USER_ID'',''EMPLOYEE_NAME'',''FLM'',''Ad_Sales'',''Client_Customer_id'',''Customer_name'',''Specialty '',''brand'',''Class'',''Planned_calls'',''total_call'',''Last_visit' ;
      for m in 1..v_max_visit loop
          v_visit.extend;
          v_visit(m) := '';
          v_insert_col_head := v_insert_col_head || ''',''VISIT_' || m || '';

      end loop m;
      v_insert_col_head := v_insert_col_head || ''')';
      execute immediate v_insert_col_head;

    -------------------till here i am not getting any error 
      for a in al loop
        for c in (select distinct CCA_USER_ID,FLM,Ad_Sales,Client_Customer_id,Customer_name,Specialty,brand,class,Planned_calls,total_call,Last_visit from TMP_BMS_RPT_3 where employee_name = a.employee_name and team_name=a.team_name and employee_name  in('JAY DESAI')   order by 1) loop
          j := 1;

            v_insert_sql := 'insert into tmp_BMS_monthly_report (Team_name,CCA_USER_ID,EMPLOYEE_NAME,FLM,Ad_Sales,Client_Customer_id,Customer_name,Specialty,brand,Class,Planned_calls,total_call,Last_visit';
            v_insert_sql_val := ' VALUES (''' || a.team_name
                                  || ''', ''' || c.CCA_USER_ID
                                  || ''', ''' || a.EMPLOYEE_NAME
                                  || ''', ''' || c.FLM
                                  || ''', ''' || c.ad_sales
                                  || ''', ''' || c.Client_Customer_id
                                  || ''', ''' || c.Customer_name
                                  || ''', ''' || c.Specialty
                                  || ''', ''' || c.brand
                                  || ''', ''' || c.Class
                                  || ''', ''' || c.Planned_calls
                                  || ''', ''' || c.total_call
                                  || ''', ''' || c.Last_visit;


            for dt in (select distinct visit_date from TMP_BMS_RPT_3 where employee_name = a.employee_name and Customer_name=c.Customer_name and c.total_call=total_call and  employee_name in('JAY DESAI')  order by 1)
                   loop
                  v_visit(j) := dt.visit_date;
                  dbms_output.put_line(v_visit(j));
                  v_insert_sql := v_insert_sql || ',VISIT_' ||j ;
                  v_insert_sql_val := v_insert_sql_val || ''', ''' || v_visit(j);
                  j := j + 1;
            end loop dt;
           v_insert_sql := v_insert_sql || ')';
           v_insert_sql_val := v_insert_sql_val || ''')';
           v_insert_sql := v_insert_sql || v_insert_sql_val;
        --dbms_output.put_line(v_insert_sql);
          execute immediate v_insert_sql;
        end loop c;
      end loop a;
      commit;

    --exception
    -- when others then
    --    dbms_output.put_line(SQLCode || ' - ' || SQLERRM );
    end;
    /
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment to type varray vairable is wrong, varray assignment works like (1,2,3,4) column wise and you assigning as rows, so no worries you use type table instead of varray, check the below example:

```
type v_dt is table of date index by binary_integer;
          v_visit v_dt ;
```